# How we can get Id (Name ) of cache and clear that while website loading in javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache

I want to clear cache of browser while website loading. How we can get Id (Name) of cache and clear in java script. This I have to to implement bcz when user fill some form then at that time there is autosuggestion will came which is from cache and I want to avoid that autosuggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can use `autocomplete="off"` in your input field.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```